# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting The model item passed into the dictionary error in visual studio 2015. The Error message says :`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[CmsShoppingCart.Models.Data.ProductDTO]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CmsShoppingCart.Models.ViewModels.Shop.ProductVM]'.

and in visual studio I'm getting "UNREACHABLE CODE DETECTED" at return View(productVMList);
What I want to achieve is that to view the list of products and working search bar for products.
My controller is

```
public ActionResult Category(string name,string searchString)
        {
        // Declare a list of ProductVM
        List<ProductVM> productVMList;

        using (Db db = new Db())
        {
            // Get category id
            CategoryDTO categoryDTO = db.Categories.Where(x => x.Slug == name).FirstOrDefault();
            int catId = categoryDTO.Id;

            // Init the list
            productVMList = db.Products.ToArray().Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId).Select(x => new ProductVM(x)).ToList();

            // Get category name
            var productCat = db.Products.Where(x => x.CategoryId == catId).FirstOrDefault();
            ViewBag.CategoryName = productCat.CategoryName;
        }

        var product = from c in db.Products
                      select c;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            product = product.Where(c => c.Name == searchString);
        }
        return View(product);

        // Return view with list 
        return View(productVMList);
    }
```

And View is

```
@model IEnumerable<CmsShoppingCart.Models.ViewModels.Shop.ProductVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = ViewBag.CategoryName;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.CategoryName</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Shop", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        Search By Products @Html.TextBox("searchString")
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </div>
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Description
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)

                </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Price", "Category", new { SortOrder = ViewBag.Price })
            $@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price, new { SortOrder = ViewBag.Price })

        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/shop/product-details/@item.Slug">
                <img src="/Images/Uploads/Products/@item.Id/Thumbs/@item.ImageName" />
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="/shop/product-details/@item.Slug">Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

[My Error in Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9liU.png)

Comment: Remove `return View(product);` and adjust the query with `ToList()` (e.g. `product.Where(c => c.Name == searchString).Select(x => new ProductVM { ... }).ToList()` so that it returns `ProductVM`.

Comment: Delete your `return View(product);` line of code

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto What should I pass in {...}

Comment: All properties of your viewmodel. But... since you're already have `productVMList`, no need to `return View(product)` anymore.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CmsShoppingCart.Models.ViewModels.Shop.ProductVM>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CmsShoppingCart.Models.Data.ProductDTO>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)  
 This error occured while not passing any parameter in curly Brackets